# source code of contacts - application of iPhone

Tags: iphone, mobile-safari, contacts

I have seen the Contacts in iPhone Simulator.

I want to create an application similar like that.

Does apple provide open source of that " Contacts " application.

Similarly, Does apple provide source code of " Safari ",

So we can create our own browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create "Safari" You can just use a UIWebview with a tool bar. It's rather trivial. a tutorial is here:

http://icodeblog.com/2008/12/19/iphone-coding-learning-about-uiwebviews-by-creating-a-web-browser/

Contacts is slightly more involved, you can use the Adress Book Frameworks.  There are Cocoa Touch classes to bring specific view controllers into existence. These are like the photo picker where you give up control of the UI until you recieve a callback.  There is also a C-based API for direct manipulation of the contacts DB from within your app.

http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/200-QuickStart/QuickStart.html

Answer (score 3):

They don't provide the source code. You have a `UIWevView` that you can use to render web pages using WebKit, and you can access the address book information by using the [Address Book framework](http://developer.apple.com/IPhone/library/documentation/ContactData/Conceptual/AddressBookProgrammingGuideforiPhone/100-Introduction/Introduction.html).